# Linking Error in Class Import

Tags: objective-c, ipad

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CustomerNameViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref-to-CustomerNameViewController in Kunden.o
```

I am getting this error even i have already imported header file of "CustomerViewController.h" in "Kunden.h"

Help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `CustomerNameViewController.m` (**implementation** file for CustomerNameViewController class) is added to a target you're building.